# logical replicaiton monitoring using pg_stat_subscription

Tags: postgresql

To monitor logical replication, I use the pg_stat_subscription view and perform the following calculation to determine if some lag exists.

```
(last_msg_receipt_time - last_msg_send_time)
```

is this test correct or would it be more accurate to use

```
(latest_end_time - last_msg_send_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replication lag, remaining amount of data for the replica to catch up with the primary, can be measured as LSN gap.

```
select pg_current_wal_lsn() - replay_lsn lsn_lag from pg_stat_replication;
```

Comment: how to get time difference too. like how much time target is lagging from primary wal generation